# Replace specific space with non-breakable space in PHP

Tags: php, regex, replace, numbers

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to coding with php and its my first time posting to stackoverflow. I'm having some problems with my code. I'm trying to search through a string for a number followed by a space followed by another number and replace the space with a non-breakable space. I know I need to use regex, but I still can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is:

```
echo replaceSpace("hello world ! 1 234");
function replaceSpace( $text ){        
   $brokenspace = array(" !", " ?", " ;", " :", " …", "« ", " »", "( ", " )");
   $fixedspace = array("&nbsp;!", "&nbsp;?", "&nbsp;;", "&nbsp;:", "&nbsp;»", "&nbsp;…", "«&nbsp;", "(&nbsp;", "&nbsp;)");

   return str_replace( $brokenspace , $fixedspace, $text );            
}
```

I want my output to be:

> hello world(nbsp)! 1(nbsp)234

Comment: regex pattern wise, are you using something like this? http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=(%5B0-9%5D%2B%20%5B0-9%5D%2B)&input=2%203%205%206%204%205%209%2078%20%204%205%2066%204%205%206%20%20%2012

Comment: regexpal is for javascript. For PHP you can use http://regex101.com or http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com

Comment: Added my code @scrowler

Comment: Is your original string an html file?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte No

Comment: you want to take @zamnuts answer below, put it into your function like `$str = str_replace( $brokenspace, $fixedspace, $text );`, then `return $withNbsp;`, and mark his answer as correct.

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
<?php
$str = 'Some string has 30 characters and 1 line.';
$withNbsp = preg_replace('/([0-9]+)\s(\w)/', '$1&nbsp;$2', $str);
echo $withNbsp; // Some string has 30&nbsp;characters and 1&nbsp;line.
?>
```

The key is the regex: `/([0-9]+)\s(\w)/`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(?<=[0-9]) (?=[0-9])| (?=[!?:;…»)])|(?<=[«(]) ~i', '&nbsp;', $yourString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here on how you can go about performing this.

You can continue using the [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) method and combine a [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) call to insert a non breaking space between a number followed by whitespace and another number.

```
echo _replace('hello world ! 1 234');

function _replace($text) { 
    $map = array(' !' => '&nbsp;!', ' ?' => '&nbsp;?', 
                 ' ;' => '&nbsp;;', ' :' => '&nbsp;:', 
                 ' …' => '&nbsp;…', ' »' => '&nbsp;»',
                 ' )' => '&nbsp;)', '( ' => '(&nbsp;', 
                 '« ' => '«&nbsp;'
                );
    $text = str_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $text);
    return preg_replace('/(?<![^0-9]) (?=[0-9])/', '&nbsp;', $text);
}
```

You can use the cheaper [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/strtr) to translate characters and replace your substrings. Along with doing this, you can use an associative array for readability and [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) inside your function.

```
echo _replace('hello world ! 1 234');

function _replace($text) { 
   $text = strtr($text, 
         array(' !' => '&nbsp;!', ' ?' => '&nbsp;?',
               ' ;' => '&nbsp;;', ' :' => '&nbsp;:', 
               ' …' => '&nbsp;…', ' »' => '&nbsp;»',
               ' )' => '&nbsp;)', '( ' => '(&nbsp;', 
               '« ' => '«&nbsp;'));

   return preg_replace('/(?<![^0-9]) (?=[0-9])/', '&nbsp;', $text);
}
```

You can replace all of the above using a single [`preg_replace()`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) call and a combined regular expression.

```
$s = preg_replace('/ (?=[!?;:…»)])|(?<![^0-9]) (?=[0-9])|(?<![^«(]) /', '&nbsp;', $s);
```